# Ghidra wrong function arguments and returns

Tags: ghidra

I'm a newbie here but I'm stuck with this problem.

I'm trying to decompile a function that in turns call another function (named      charTranslateToHex).

This is the **charTranslateToHex assembly code**

```
                     *************************************************************
                     *                           FUNCTION                          
                     *************************************************************
                     undefined  __stdcall  charTranslateToHex (uint  param_1 , ui
     undefined         r0:1           <RETURN>
     uint              r0:4           param_1
     uint              r1:4           param_2
     undefined4        r2:4           param_3
     undefined2        Stack[-0xc]:2  local_c                                 XREF[2]:     000c1284 (W) , 
                                                                                           000c128c (W)   
                     charTranslateToHex                              XREF[3]:     Entry Point (*) , 
                                                                                  charTranslateToHex:0002a230 (T) , 
                                                                                  charTranslateToHex:0002a238 (c) , 
                                                                                  000f389c (*)   
000c1278 07  40  2d  e9    stmdb      sp!,{param_1  param_2  param_3  lr}
000c127c 00  10  a0  e3    mov        param_2 ,#0x0
000c1280 08  30  8d  e2    add        r3,sp,#0x8
000c1284 b4  10  cd  e1    strh       param_2 ,[sp,#local_c ]
000c1288 10  20  a0  e3    mov        param_3 ,#0x10
000c128c 04  00  63  e5    strb       param_1 ,[r3,#local_c ]!
000c1290 03  00  a0  e1    cpy        param_1 ,r3
000c1294 25  a6  fd  eb    bl         strtoul                                          ulong strtoul(char * __nptr, cha
000c1298 0e  80  bd  e8    ldmia      sp!,{param_2  param_3  r3 pc}
```

and this is how Ghidra decompile it:

```
void charTranslateToHex(uint param_1,uint param_2,undefined4 param_3)

{
  uint local_c;
  undefined4 uStack8;
  
  local_c = param_2 & 0xffff0000;
  local_c = local_c | param_1 & 0xff;
  uStack8 = param_3;
  strtoul((char *)&local_c,(char **)0x0,0x10);
  return;
}
```

Now back to the **main function**:

```
......
                             LAB_000c1410                                    XREF[1]:     000c13c4 (j)   
        000c1410 00  00  6a  e0    rsb        param_1 ,r10 ,param_1
        000c1414 48  10  8d  e2    add        param_2 ,sp,#0x48
        000c1418 00  30  81  e0    add        param_4 ,param_2 ,param_1
        000c141c 08  00  8d  e5    str        param_1 ,[sp,#local_60 ]
        000c1420 1d  00  53  e5    ldrb       param_1 ,[r3,#local_3d ]
        000c1424 04  90  a0  e1    cpy        r9,r4
        000c1428 80  a3  fd  eb    bl         charTranslateToHex                               undefined charTranslateToHex(uin
        000c142c 24  31  9f  e5    ldr        param_4 ,[DAT_000c1558 ]                          = 0001529Dh
        000c1430 00  60  a0  e3    mov        r6,#0x0
        000c1434 10  00  8d  e5    str        param_1 ,[sp,#local_58 ]
        000c1438 03  30  8f  e0    add        param_4 ,pc,param_4
        000c143c 14  30  8d  e5    str        param_4 =>DAT_000d66dd ,[sp,#local_54 ]            = 25h    %
......
```

and this is the decompiled version:

```
iVar3 = sVar5 - uVar8;
uVar12 = charTranslateToHex((uint)local_3d[iVar3],(uint)&stack0xffffffe0,uVar10);
uVar9 = (uint)uVar12;
uVar11 = 0;
__s = param_4;
```

I'm not understanding why the charTranslateToHex requires three parameters and why it returns void despite the main function using it's return value.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Decompilation is not an exact science. Sometimes, you must manually assist with the process.

Comment: Hi @multithr3at3d thank you for your comment. I attached the code, can you help me understand how to assist the decompiler in this case?

Answer (score 3):

### Theory

The first important thing to understand is that the decompiler always decompiles only a single function at once and that the results of this analysis are *not* propagated by default. So the decompiler will happily analyse a function like `charTranslateToHex` and come to the conclusion that it uses 3 parameters and returns none, but decompile a function that calls `charTranslateToHex`, e.g. `main` and conclude that based on *only* the code in `main` that `charTranslateToHex` takes 3 argument and returns something. The important step now is deciding which interpretation to trust and "commiting" to it.

### Commit Parameter ID

This can be done manually via `Commit Parameter ID` in the context menu of the decompiler listing, or by using the analysis pass that does this for all functions.

### What changes after commiting?

Now the decompiler will assume that `charTranslateToHex` has the function signature you commited, e.g. `void charTranslateToHex(uint param_1,uint param_2,undefined4 param_3)` instead of trying to infer it from the context in `main`. But in this case this would actually be wrong and lead to worse results!

### Why is it wrong?

Because the decompiler doesn't know that call to `strtoul` inside `charTranslateToHex` actually returns something, that will then be automatically returned as the result of `charTranslateToHex`. This is the same problem as your question, now just with `charTranslateToHex` as the caller, and `strtoul` as the callee, instead of `main` as the caller and `charTranslateToHex`. There is no function signature available for `strtoul`, so it is unknown if it returns something.

You can either manually apply the correct signature `unsigned long int strtoul (const char* str, char** endptr, int base);` or look for the appropriate Ghidra Data Type Archive that includes this library function. Then the decompiler will correctly infer that `charTranslateToHex` returns something and change the signature of `charTranslateToHex`.

Comment: wow this was gold! Just one point remaining: it seems that this function is trying to return more then one value (I think it has to do with the ldmia instruction). Just out of curiosity, how could a C program have been compiled to this instruction? Maybe this code was processed by some sort of code obfuscator?

Comment: umh, actually the strtoul signature was correct (ulong strtoul (char * __nptr, char * * __endptr, int __base)). I still think it's something related to the ldmia instruction

Comment: is the `ldmia` really the last instruction of the function? The code doesn't look like it is obfuscated on purpose, probably just some optimization that Ghidra doesn't handle properly by default

Comment: yes, it's really the last instruction...